# How to create Sum Partial Payment and Outstanding Payment

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 table like below:-

```
Table: Invoice
InvDate     InvNo   InvAmount
01/01/2016  T0001   3000
02/01/2016  T0002   8000

Table: Payment
ResDate     ResType ResNo   ResAmount   InvNo
01/01/2016  C       R0001   3000        T0001
02/01/2016  P       R0002   2000        T0002
04/01/2016  P       R0003   2000        T0002
```

What I need the output like below:-

```
InvDate     InvNo   InvAmount   Cash    Partial Balance
01/01/2016  T0001   3000        3000    -       0
02/01/2016  T0002   8000        -       4000    4000
```

I lost my query when trying to put a value into new column Cash if payment are cash and Sum(Payment Partial) on Partial then calculate a Balance if still outstanding.

I don't know how to build this query.. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT i.invdate, i.invno, i.invamount,
       sum(CASE WHEN p.restype = 'C' THEN p.resamount END) AS cash,
       sum(CASE WHEN p.restype = 'P' THEN p.resamount END) AS partial,
       i.invamount - sum(p.resamount) AS balance
FROM invoice i
   JOIN payment p USING (invno)
GROUP BY i.invdate, i.invno, i.invamount
ORDER BY i.invdate;

┌────────────┬───────┬───────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│  invdate   │ invno │ invamount │  cash   │ partial │ balance │
├────────────┼───────┼───────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 2016-01-01 │ T0001 │   3000.00 │ 3000.00 │         │    0.00 │
│ 2016-02-01 │ T0002 │   8000.00 │         │ 4000.00 │ 4000.00 │
└────────────┴───────┴───────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply and so fast. If I like to put "-" if no value on partial or cash how? Anyway your answer already save my days. Thanks you so much.